# run python scripts remotely including modules

Tags: python

i have bash script with embedded python code that included importing python modules named :pyVim and  pyVmomi 
i am use to running bash scripts from a remote server like this:
bash <(curl http://remote_server/script)
but if i run my script as above ,i am getting :

" ImportError: No module named pyVim"

i know that if i will copy the modules locally ,it will work ,but i wonder

if i can run it remotely ,while the modules exits on the remote server?

Comment: Why don't you connect through ssh and run the script from the server?

Comment: You seem to be using the word "remote" to describe both sides. The module needs to be visible to the embedded python somehow. Maybe its installed on the embedded side or the embedded side as mapped a drive. When you trigger the script on the embedded side's web server, it would be a real disaster if it could somehow come back and read your local machine.